# Which of these sentence is correct given the subject of the sentence?

Tags: phrases, slang

Which of these sentence is correct?

“I am a person who likes their hair”

(we conjugate with “person” we use “their” as a gender-neutral pronoun or do we put “his?”)

“I am a person who like her hair”

(I am a girl, so I conjugate with ‘I’)

Could you tell me if we conjugate with “person” or with “I”?

Other sentences could be:

“I am a person who follows their/his dreams”
Or...

“I am a person who follow her dreams”

My question is more, if we conjugate with the word “person”, how does “person” need to be conjugated?

( I am confused with that singular “they” and if we must use it with words such as “person”, “someone”, “somebody”...)

**seeking something grammatically correct!!

Thank you ever so much!

Comment: Neither is 'incorrect' - it's entirely up to you, and may be dependent on context, whether you  want to refer to yourself in a gender-neutral way  or as a female. (If the latter, please note  that it's _likes her_ and _follows her_.)

Comment: No, my question is what is grammatically correct. I am a girl, but what is correct. Do we conjugate with person or I?

Comment: "Who" has gender-neutral "person" as antecedent, so I'd be inclined to use gender-neutral "their".

Comment: So in an essay, I must write : “I am a person who follows their dreams” because “who” has for antecedent “person” and “person” must be followed by a gender neutral pronoun? I can’t say “her” given I am a girl? (Sorry I am not a native speaker so I am a bit confused...)

Comment: Here I’ll try to clarify things a little: in the sentence “I am a person who follows her dreams”, is it incorrect because I wrote “her” and we conjugated with “person” which is a neutral noun, so I was supposed to put “their” instead? Is : “I am a person who follows her dreams.” grammatically correct? If not, what should I write instead?

Comment: Since "person" refers to "I", it would be grammatically OK to use "her". Nevertheless, my preference would be to use "their", which is certainly grammatically fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers!! It’s been enormously helpful to me :)

Comment: I would use "her" in "I am a **girl** who likes **her** hair".

Comment: Perfect! I will do as you say! A big thanks from Canada :)